how to write regular expression fetch any task id base upon due date and time with compare with current date and time in jmeter
how to write regular expression fetch any task id base upon due date and time with compare with current date and time in JMeter.
I need a regular expression for my issue.
I want to fetch the task id if due date & time is greater than current date & time
